# Minimal complexity of the algorithm when working with ArrayList

Tags: java

There are two ArrayLists. A = [1,2,3] B = [1,2,4].
It is necessary to obtain ArrayList A, which consists of two of these ArrayLists A and B. (The data should be sorted in ascending order).
The algorithm should have the least time complexity, and use few resources.
My attempt to solve this problem.
Is there a better option?

```
ArrayList<Integer> a= new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,3,5));
ArrayList<Integer> b= new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,4,6));
merge(a,b);
static void merge(ArrayList a,ArrayList b) {
        a.addAll(b);
        Collections.sort(a);                      
  }
```

Comment: Two of the lists are already sorted. So merging in `O(n)` will be the least time complexity. While your code is `O(n log n)` at least, given the `sort`.

Comment: `Collections.sort()` has `O(nlogn)` complexity and merging sorted lists can be done in `O(n)`

Comment: You can use [Merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Especially, If source arrays are already sorted.

Comment: These ArrayLists are an example. There may also be such ArrayLists: A = [8,3,6] B = [1,7,2]. Therefore, they still need to be sorted.